# error: Unable to resolve module `react/lib/ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin`

Tags: reactjs, module, native

can anayone tell me about that error.
Unable to resolve module `react/lib/ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin` from `G:\\react native\\manager\\node_modules\\react-addons-pure-render-mixin\\index.js`: Module does not exist in the module map [image]

Comment: Did you npm install?

Comment: yes version 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

This  solution worked for me exactly

Source -- https://github.com/developit/preact-compat/issues/254

Install the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-pure-render-mixin published by gaeron.

Then create following path

node_modules/react/lib/ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin.js

Now copy the below line to above created path

module.exports = require('react-addons-pure-render-mixin');